# Slow request with ORDER and LIMIT clauses

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 11

I have about 3 million rows in the database

the time to execute this request is 2 seconds

```
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT Student.ID AS id,
     Student.name AS name,  Student.age AS age,dept.name,college.name
     FROM Student as Student 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN department dept 
     on dept.id=Student.dept_id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN college college 
     on college.id=dept.college_id  
      WHERE  Student.usertran_id = 'EM-001' 

     ORDER BY Student.datesendjc desc

 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

the result :

```
 "Limit  (cost=332499.36..332500.52 rows=10 width=30) (actual time=1707.668..1713.719 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=332499.36..332574.50 rows=644 width=30) (actual time=1707.663..1713.684 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=331499.33..331500.14 rows=322 width=30) (actual time=1677.797..1677.806 rows=6 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: student.datesendjc DESC"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on student  (cost=0.00..331492.38 rows=322 width=30) (actual time=298.782..1677.567 rows=10 loops=3)"
"                    Filter: ((usertran_id)::text = 'EM-001'::text)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1494350"
"Planning Time: 3.414 ms"
"Execution Time: 1713.871 ms"
```

the duration of execution without  **ORDER BY Student.datesendjc desc**
 is 166.770 ms

I try also to make **ANALYZE Student**

I want to have an execution time like or almost equal to the request without **ORDER BY Student.datesendjc desc**

Comment: Where's the `LIMIT` clause in that query?

Comment: Looks like you'll need an index on that column.

Comment: sorry I forget the limit in the query,  I try also without success to add indesx CREATE INDEX pk_Student_date
ON Student (id, datesendjc DESC);

Comment: The index would need to be on `Student(usertran_id, datesendjc)` - that's what you are selecting by.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without the definitions of the tables, including keys and indexes.

Comment: @Bergi You should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a query that filters with `WHERE  Student.usertran_id =` and has an `ORDER BY Student.datesendjc desc` clause, you will need to create an index on `Student(usertran_id, datesendjc)`.